# Botón con JLabel en Eclipse y subrayado al pasar el Mouse

Tags: java

Estoy haciendo un Log In en Eclipse y quiero agregar un JLabel con el mensaje "Olvidaste tu usuario?".

Me gustaría que al pasar el Mouse, este se subraye. Al alejar el Mouse, vuelva a como estaba antes.

Tengo entendido que necesitaría:

1. `mouseClicked` para lo que tenga que hacer después.
2. `mouseEntered` para mostrar el texto subrayado.
3. `mouseExited` para mostrar el texto sin el subrayado.

El código que tengo hasta ahora:

```
JLabel lblolvidasteTuUsuario = new JLabel("Olvidaste tu usuario?");
        lblolvidasteTuUsuario.setCursor(Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(Cursor.HAND_CURSOR));
        lblolvidasteTuUsuario.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent arg0) {
                System.out.println("Clikeado");
                // aquí abriré otra ventana
            }
            @Override
            public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
                // subrayado ?
            }
            @Override
            public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
                // no subrayado ?
            }
        });
        lblolvidasteTuUsuario.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.RIGHT);
        lblolvidasteTuUsuario.setFont(new Font("Calibri", Font.BOLD, 14));
        lblolvidasteTuUsuario.setBounds(150, 298, 194, 16);
        contentPane.add(lblolvidasteTuUsuario);
```

Cómo puedo subrayar el JLabel y cómo se lo quito?.

La idea es tener una especie de botón y que el usuario sepa si tiene el Mouse encima o no.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El código que necesitas para subrayar es:

```
JLabel lblolvidasteTuUsuario = new JLabel("Underlined Label");
    Font font = lblolvidasteTuUsuario.getFont();
    Map<TextAttribute, Object> attributes = new HashMap<>(font.getAttributes());
    attributes.put(TextAttribute.UNDERLINE, TextAttribute.UNDERLINE_ON);
    lblolvidasteTuUsuario.setFont(font.deriveFont(attributes));
```

Para quitar el subrayado es similar solo que se usa el -1 como parámetro.

```
JLabel lblolvidasteTuUsuario = new JLabel("Underlined Label");
Font font = lblolvidasteTuUsuario.getFont();
Map<TextAttribute, Object> attributes = new HashMap<>(font.getAttributes());
attributes.put(TextAttribute.UNDERLINE, -1);
lblolvidasteTuUsuario.setFont(font.deriveFont(attributes));
```

Ahora empleando los eventos y en tu caso:

```
JLabel lblolvidasteTuUsuario = new JLabel("Olvidaste tu usuario?");
        lblolvidasteTuUsuario.setCursor(Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(Cursor.HAND_CURSOR));
        lblolvidasteTuUsuario.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent arg0) {
                System.out.println("Clikeado");
                // aquí abriré otra ventana
            }
            @Override
            public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
                // subrayado 
               Font font = lblolvidasteTuUsuario.getFont();
               Map<TextAttribute, Object> attributes = new HashMap<>(font.getAttributes());
               attributes.put(TextAttribute.UNDERLINE, TextAttribute.UNDERLINE_ON);
               lblolvidasteTuUsuario.setFont(font.deriveFont(attributes));
            }
            @Override
            public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
                // no subrayado 
                Font font = lblolvidasteTuUsuario.getFont();
                Map<TextAttribute, Object> attributes = new HashMap<>(font.getAttributes());
                attributes.put(TextAttribute.UNDERLINE, -1);
                lblolvidasteTuUsuario.setFont(font.deriveFont(attributes));
                }
        });
        lblolvidasteTuUsuario.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.RIGHT);
        lblolvidasteTuUsuario.setFont(new Font("Calibri", Font.BOLD, 14));
        lblolvidasteTuUsuario.setBounds(150, 298, 194, 16);
        contentPane.add(lblolvidasteTuUsuario);
```

Comment: Hola Victor, gracias por tu ayuda, funciona, pero, a la vez estoy recibiendo un mensaje (no un error) diciendo: Type safety: The method put(Object, Object) belongs to the raw type Map. References to generic type Map<K,V> should be parameterized. La línea que provoca el mensaje es: attributes.put(TextAttribute.UNDERLINE, TextAttribute.UNDERLINE_ON); Qué será?.

Comment: Hola Roberto, la advertencia te aconseja que parametrices Map, es decir que la sentencia de declaración: Map attributes = font.getAttributes(); sea parametrizada de esta forma: Map<TextAttribute,?> attributes = font.getAttributes(); Pruébalo y comenta :)

Comment: Hola Victor, no me ha funcionado el código para parametrizar Map que me has dado. Busqué en otros sitios una solución y he encontrado uno que funciona perfecto. Es: "Map<TextAttribute, Object> attributes = new HashMap<>(font.getAttributes());". Gracias por toda tu ayuda Victor. Edita tu respuesta y agrega esa línea de código que te he dado como solución al problema del mensaje de parametrización, de esa forma, otros pueden solucionarlo también y encontrar todo en 1 sola respuesta.